# Pop up window with unlock screen

Tags: javascript, java

In my screen there is popup for login n register when i move out of that pop ups my screen will be locked to come out of that i should reload the page.
Is there any way to avoid the locking of the screen?

Comment: What is your context ? Is it a web app or standalone app?where is the code

Comment: Please have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask